# Can you point out the issue with ListView in this code?

Tags: android, listview

Following is some test code , done to recreate a strange bug: After deleting some items from a ListView , it stops refreshing when data is invalidated. More items are deleted but list does not refresh. Even Log cat does not show debug messages for deletion. I will appreciate if any one could find out what's wrong.

Item Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              />
    <Button android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Item class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Item implements View.OnClickListener {
    private String name;
    private View itemView;
    private MyActivity owner;

    //--- getters--
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public View getView() {
        return itemView;
    }

    public Item(String n, Context c , MyActivity o)
    {
        //---store the name given--
        name = n;
        //---store reference to the owner activity--
        owner = o;

        //--- create a View for this item----
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item,null);

        //---set up data to show--
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        Button deleteButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        nameTextView.setText(name);

        //---set up events to be handled--
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Log.d("My_Test","Item: Hello world, my name is " + name);
    }

    //----request owner to delete this item---
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d("My_Test","Item:"+name+" requesting owner to delete me");
        owner.deleteItem(this);
    }
```

Activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
<ListView android:id="@+id/myListView"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          />
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<Item> myItems;
    private ListView myListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<Item> myArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //-----adapter for item list----
        //----since each item has its own view , it just returns the same---
        myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this,0){

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)      {
              Item item = getItem(position);
              Log.d("My_Test","Adapter : View for Item: " + item.getName() +"is requested." );
              return item.getView();
            }

        };

        //-----set up my list view with the adapter------
        myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        myListView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);

        //------add items-------
        //----each item has its own view and a reference to this activity as their owner----
        myArrayAdapter.add(new Item("Sunday", this, this));
        myArrayAdapter.add(new Item("Monday", this, this));
        myArrayAdapter.add(new Item("Tuesday", this, this));
        myArrayAdapter.add(new Item("Wednesday", this, this));
        myArrayAdapter.add(new Item("Thursday", this, this));
        myArrayAdapter.add(new Item("Friday", this, this));
        myArrayAdapter.add(new Item("Saturday", this, this));

        myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    //----- called by items requesting to be deleted from the item list----
    public void deleteItem(Item item) {
        myArrayAdapter.remove(item);
        Log.d("My_Test","Owner : Deleted item :" + item.getName());
        myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Looks like ListView stops re-drawing it self. Even when List Item is no more in the item array, and `myAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();` is called, The List Item stays visible , with further code execution some how blocked.

Comment: try myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Why are you trying to manage an arraylist inside of an adapter? You do realize the adapter already performs all of these functions for you? You should only have to override the getView method. If you want to modify.. call adapter.add() or adapter.delete() and then notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: @Sharath G Already tried, same result.

Comment: @Joel `BaseAdapter` does not manages arrays for you.

Comment: @Akshay That's what is wierd, no error, Log cat stops showing my debug messages.

Comment: @wigman You should be using ArrayAdapter<>, since that is exactly what you are trying to mimic with a base adapter... that does all of it for you...

Comment: And if you use an ArrayAdapter, you can call adapter.remove() to delete an item.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged only tells any Views to update themselves from the underlying data; it does not affect the list itself.

Comment: @Joel I'm using custom Views with buttons and event handlers as List Items. I don't know how to do that with an `ArrayAdapter<>`

Comment: @wigman You do it the exact same way.. BaseAdapter is a superclass of ArrayAdapter.. so it has all of the same functions.

Comment: @Joel Using `ArrayAdapter<>`. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ArrayAdapter to do this. Try something like this instead...

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity{
    private ListView myListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<Item> myArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this,R.layout.item){    
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View returnedView = convertView;

                //inflate your view here
                if(returnedView == null){
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    returnedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item,null);
                }

                final Item item = getItem(position);

                //set the views
                if(returnedView != null){
                    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) returnedView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
                    nameTextView.setText(item.getName());
                    Button deleteButton = (Button) returnedView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
                    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            remove(item);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });

                }

                return returnedView;
            }
        };

        myArrayAdapter.add(new Item("Sunday"));
        myArrayAdapter.add(new Item("Monday"));
        myArrayAdapter.add(new Item("Tuesday"));
        myArrayAdapter.add(new Item("Wednesday"));
        myArrayAdapter.add(new Item("Thursday"));
        myArrayAdapter.add(new Item("Friday"));
        myArrayAdapter.add(new Item("Saturday"));

        myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        myListView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);

    }
}

public class Item{

    private String name;

    public Item(String n){
        this.name = n;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Issue is not resolved with `ArrayAdapter'. Anyways, thanks for explaining 'ArrayAdaper' usage. I've updated the code.

Comment: so the delete function still does not work right? Can you explain how an item requests to be deleted from the item list?

Comment: every item has a reference to main Activity called owner. When the delete button of Item is clicked , it calls owner to delete it passing itself as parameter: `owner.deleteItem(this)` . The owner activity calls `myArrayAdapter.remove(item)` to delete the item. Then it calls `myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh the list view.

Comment: May I ask why you are giving each item a reference to an activity? There must be a better way to do that.. By OOP standards.. I dont think an activity is an attribute of item. It is generally bad practice to mix your views and application logic. Can you post the code for item.getView() ? I can show you what I mean.

Comment: Scroll to top, Complete Code for Both classes is already posted in the question. I agree, it not OOPS standard, but I'm out of ideas of any good pattern. I need a good pattern for this: A ListView with DataItems. Each data Item's view has one or more controls to manipulate or delete that item.

Comment: @wingman I will show you how i would implement this.. see edit.  This should work.. and it is just much easier to work with. If you wanted, you could just create a separate class that extends array adapter if it gets to messy.

Comment: Thanks, It works :) . So, all Inflating stuff in Adapters only. Though I still can't exactly nail down what specific error that was, but this

Comment: Yeah I don't know what was happening earlier.. all I know is that it is helps to separate things and simplify code! Best of Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Looking inside the working of ListViews and ListAdapters, I came to know there's a lot of recycling of objects, specifically List View Item Objects which adapters produce. Here are the lessons learnt along with solution to Original problem:

- When a `ListView` has to draw/show a list item, it requests a `View` from `ListAdapter`, and some times (NOT ALWAYS) also provides an old `View` object to reuse. This reuse of objects is there so as to increase performance,there's an in built *Re-Cycler* in `ListView` to do this, why inflate new layouts for each new list item, when there are already some whose properties can be modified so that they look like the new view item. Until this point , its OK for adapter to change some text on old views and give them back, or create new ones if no recycled views are available, or even discard recyclable views and always create new one.
- However, If your List Item's state is more than just some text in a `TextView` , that is, another object is registered as an `onClickListener` for your list item, or your list item has a reference to some object somewhere and vice-verca; it is NOT OK for adapter to just change appearance of the reusable Views or simply discard them. **Adapter has to update entire state of a reusable item.** that includes de-registering old event listeners, re-registering new ones and updating all reference to external objects that may be there.

Changed `getView()` method for adapter to:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)      {

    Item item = getItem(position);
    Log.d("My_Test","Adapter : View for Item: " + item.getName() +"is requested." );

    if(convertView != null)
    {
        (convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton))
                .setOnClickListener(item);
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView))
                .setText(item.getName());
        return convertView;
    }
    else
    {
        return item.getView();
    }
}
```

NOTE: While always creating new items in this case does not cause any errors, the `ListView` fails to detect changes and redraw. Making use of recycled items seems to solve this.

Comment: Well, actually, my answer solved your problem.. and should still be selected as the answer. What you are saying is correct and is an optimization; however, is not an answer to the original question.